# How do I watch my webcam's feed on Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video

In Windows I can open "My Computer" and click on the "Webcam" icon to get a feed from my webcam. I can also take snapshots of that feed.

Can I do the same in Ubuntu? Without installing any extra applications like [Photo Booth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photo_Booth).

Comment: mplayer tv://device=/dev/video

Comment: @Stefan: can you? that's too simple!

Comment: "Without installing any extra applications". That's a pretty weird and severe constraint. I would just install something like cheese.

Comment: @phunene, well it works for me.... sometimes

Comment: @phunehehe: Yes, we can ;-)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Since you want an answer "without installing any extra applications like Photobooth," I've tried to give a solution that doesn't depend on very much.  Also I'm assuming that your webcam uses "[Video4Linux2](http://linux.bytesex.org/v4l2/)" and that it is `/dev/video0`.  If this is a modern webcam and if you only have one, these are pretty good assumptions.

From the command line:

```
$ gst-launch-0.10 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! xvimagesink
```

Note that "v4l2src" contains a lowercase L and not the number 1. On your system the command may be `gst-launch` or something starting with `gst-launch` but with a different version number. Tab completion should help you find the exact command name.  This tool is in the `gstreamer0.10-tools` package on my Ubuntu system, which is a dependency of libgstreamer, which is a dependency of a large number of the apps on my Ubuntu system and is likely present in the default installation.

### Other Applications

If you don't mind installing other applications, here is how you can do this in a few other applications. All of them can easily be installed via `apt-get` or another package manager of your choosing:

- **VLC**: `$ vlc v4l2:///dev/video0` Also, you can do this from the VLC GUI by going to File->Open Capture Device
- **mplayer**:  `mplayer tv://device=/dev/video01` (from Stefan in the comments)
- **Cheese**: This is a photobooth-like app that is very simple to use.

Comment: VLC is so flexible

Comment: Note that **Cheese** is super easy to use and comes pre-installed with Ubuntu I believe, which is nice. One can just search for it in the programs menu and launch it from there.

Comment: Neither gst-launch nor vlc work for me, getting various errors.  Answer below using `guvcview` was super simple and worked perfectly.

Comment: Note that **Cheese** is buggy and tends to just grab a camera rather than honor its -d / --device= argument

Answer (score 32):

**`guvcview`**

This program is ideal for screencasts, as it can show just the camera on a window and nothing else:

```
sudo apt-get install guvcview
guvcview
```

[image]

Then just use any screen recorder to make a feed. `recordmydesktop` works fine.

Tested on Ubuntu 18.04.

Related questions:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/536563/screen-recorder-webcam
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/48245/webcam-apps-and-ways-of-checking-if-webcam-is-working
- https://askubuntu.com/questions/348838/how-to-check-available-webcams-from-the-command-line/848390#848390

Comment: Yeah, pretty cool. I'd like to get rid of the title bar too, though... or rename it. Nice pic BTW, very "zen".

Comment: @StefanReich yes, hiding the title bar would be good. Looks like GNOME does not allow it though: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/420452/how-to-hide-title-bar-for-a-specific-window :-( Forgot why I was so happy that day! Life is generally good though, we should be happier.

Comment: Very nice, easy, smooth, works perfectly.  Should be top answer!

Comment: I cannot achieve the highest resolution supported by my webcam (which is 1920x1080).  I get 1280x720 and it's blurry.  Very disappointing... any suggestions?

Comment: @YanKingYin I'm not sure about this, let me know if you find out something, and also consider opening a separate question.

Comment: @CiroSantilli郝海东冠状病六四事件法轮功  I just bought a new HD web cam which is supported by Linux (did a web search to find a list of them).  Looks like there isn't much I could do with the old one, on Linux.  So I just donated it to the sharing shelf in the neighborhood.

Answer (score 21):

`ffplay /dev/video0` is one of the simpler methods, and will work provided you have ffmpeg installed.

To install, use `sudo apt install ffmpeg`.

Comment: Another nice simple solution!

Answer (score 11):

Or you can try mpv command

```
mpv /dev/video0
```

Comment: `/dev/video0` does not exist on my notebook. I guess, I have to activate the webcam first somehow? guvcview does that automatically.

Comment: You need to make sure that your webcam is working. I do not know your webcam model and the used Linux distribution so I cannot give you a detail suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly different syntax worked for me using mplayer:

```
mplayer -tv device=/dev/video1 tv://
```

I am using a plugged-in webcam (not the built-in).  So I changed `/dev/video0` to `/dev/video1`.  But Stefan's syntax above seemed to default to the built-in because of an argument parsing error.  See marked lines in the output:

```
baxelrod@it6598 ~ $ mplayer tv://device=/dev/video1
MPlayer 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1 (C) 2000-2016 MPlayer Team
mplayer: could not connect to socket
mplayer: No such file or directory
Failed to open LIRC support. You will not be able to use your remote control.
Playing tv://device=/dev/video1.
The filename option must be an integer: dev/video1     <--
Struct tv, field filename parsing error: dev/video1    <--
TV file format detected.
...
Selected device: Integrated Camera                     <--
...
```

When I use the syntax I posted, I don't get the error lines, and I get          this instead:

```
Selected device: UVC Camera (046d:081b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Preinstalled on Ubuntu: **Cheese**. Worked for me.

(As Gabriel Staples pointed out in a comment.)

Answer (score 1):

To stream camera over network

```
cat << EOF > index.html
<html><head><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script></head>
<body><video id="video"></video>
<script>
  var video = document.getElementById('video');
  var videoSrc = '/playlist.m3u8';
  if (Hls.isSupported()) {
    var hls = new Hls();
    hls.loadSource(videoSrc);
    hls.attachMedia(video);
    hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function() {
      video.play();
    });
  }
  else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
    video.src = videoSrc;
    video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
      video.play();
    });
  }
</script></body></html>
EOF

gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! videoconvert ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink max-files=5 &
python3 -m http.server --port 8080
```

On other side

```
vlc http://192.168.0.2:8080/playlist.m3u8
```

or open in browser `http://192.168.0.2:8080/index.html`, then right button click on image -> play.