# How to hide title bar for a specific window?

Tags: gnome3, window-title

I am running Linux Mint 18.3 with Gnome 3.18 as my desktop. I have been building a loading screen for an application I have installed (Mycroft AI). I have the animation, I have it pop up on loading, i have it closing as soon as it finishes loading.

What I DO NOT have is a loading screen with no title bar (what I have is in the screen shot below).

[image: mycroft loading screen]

As you can see, i still have the title bar. How do I remove it? The fewer apps I have to install to get this to work, the better.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Title bars/ window decorations are usually specific to the WM/program in use. GNOME doesn't support a built-in method to launch a window/program without decorations. Perhaps try using `gtk_window_set_decorated()`, with more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702762/how-to-create-a-custom-splash-screen-for-a-program).

Comment: Awesome! I formatted an answer so that the question can be closed, and anyone else seeking information will find an easily readable solution.

Comment: This question is about Linux Mint but I dare to link a similar question from askubuntu which has a wonderful one-liner solution: https://askubuntu.com/questions/906424/remove-decoration-of-single-window-in-gnome-3 [not sure if this is applicable for other distros though]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Title bars / window decorations are usually specific to the window manager in use. GNOME doesn't support a built-in method to launch a window/program without decorations, unlike window managers such as [Openbox](http://openbox.org/wiki/Main_Page).

A solution that works within GTK across any window manager is to use GTK's [`gtk_window_set_decorated()`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-decorated), with more information [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/702762/how-to-create-a-custom-splash-screen-for-a-program).

Answer (score 17):

Here's a non-programmatic solution that's at the X11 level, and needs only the `x11-utils` package, that's part of almost all distributions :

```
xprop -name 'Your window name' -format _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32c -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 2
```

If you omit the `-name` option, you will have to click the window whose title bar you want removed. You can also specify the window ID instead, with the `-id` option.

**EDIT :** My bad, the correct type of the `_MOTIF_WM_HINTS` property is 32-bit cardinal (i.e. unsigned integer, 32c), not 32-bit integer (32i), I changed the command line accordingly.

Comment: This works across distros. I was able to get this command to work in Linux Mint and have posted this on Linux Mint Forum here. The beauty of this solution is that you could tag this script with a shortcut and now with a key-chord you could toggle between visibile/invisible title bars. Here's the link: [forum-url](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2005989&sid=92f17d1b271c9352d16cbd3171f3292c#p2005989)